# Is it possible to use Jira api with "in-page" auth?

Tags: api, authentication, request, jira, credentials

The idea is I want to be able to make requests to jira api to e.g. create new issue, but I don't want to hardcode user credentials in my web app, nor in the request itself.

When a user clicks a button on my page to, for example invoke api call to automatically create 10 issues, I want them to be redirected to jira to enter credentials. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems that it certainly can be done through OAuth, described e.g here:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/